# Incompatible Archive. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10)

Tags: themes

What causes this error (generated while uploading any theme to this WP site)

```
Unpacking the package…

Incompatible Archive. PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) : 
Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
```

I've tried to upload several different popular themes to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes from the library that manages ZIP formatted archives: http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/user-guide/19?showall=1

After a quick web search, two solutions came up:

1) Which version of WordPress are you using? For version 2.8 this seems to be a known and fixed issue. Hence, an update of WordPress could help.

2) You perhaps have to increase your available hosting space.

If it's nothing of this, searching for your error message + WordPress yields many many results!

Comment: Philip: I believe its #2 from my initial research and based on what I've read. I've asked the customer to check their available disk space with their host.